# How do I access a table thats split into different pages but the same url for transfermarkt?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm having an issue where I access the first page of the table but not the rest. When i click on say tab 2, it gives me players 26-50 but i can't scrape it as it is the same URL and not a different one. Is there a way to edit my code so that I could get all the pages of the tables?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.transfermarkt.us/premier-league/transferrekorde/wettbewerb/GB1/plus/1/galerie/0?saison_id=2021&land_id=alle&ausrichtung=alle&spielerposition_id=alle&altersklasse=alle&leihe=&w_s=s&zuab=0"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')



TransferPrice = pageSoup.find_all("td",{"class","rechts hauptlink"})

transfer_prices = []
cleaned_transfer_prices = []
for i in TransferPrice:
    transfer_prices.append(i.text)
for i in transfer_prices:
    i = i[1:-1]
    i = float(i)
    cleaned_transfer_prices.append(i)
cleaned_transfer_prices

some_list = []
#Players = pageSoup.find_all("td",{"class", "hauptlink"})

for td_tag in pageSoup.find_all("td",{"class", "hauptlink"}):
    a_tag = td_tag.find('a')
    if a_tag == None:
        pass
    else:
        some_list.append(a_tag.text)
players = []
team_left = []
team_gone_to = []
for i in range(0,len(some_list),3):
    players.append(some_list[i])
for i in range(1,len(some_list),3):
    team_left.append(some_list[i])
for i in range(2,len(some_list),3):
    team_gone_to.append(some_list[i])

df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2['Player Name'] = players
df_2['Team Left'] = team_left
df_2['New Team'] = team_gone_to
df_2['Transfer Price'] = cleaned_transfer_prices
df_2.index+=1

df_2
```

Comment: It looks like it has different pages for each pagination: `https://www.transfermarkt.us/premier-league/transferrekorde/wettbewerb/GB1/ajax/yw1/saison_id/2021/land_id/alle/ausrichtung/alle/spielerposition_id/alle/altersklasse/alle/leihe//w_s/s/zuab/0/plus/1/galerie/0/page/1` Just change that last character to `2` and `3` to paginate via URL.

Comment: Thank you for this! I was just wondering how you got the pagination page as i changed the filter when for the table on the link you provided and I could no longer paginate it?

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong link here.

you should use this one instead: 
`https://www.transfermarkt.us/premier-league/transferrekorde/wettbewerb/GB1/ajax/yw1/saison_id/2021/land_id/alle/ausrichtung/alle/spielerposition_id/alle/altersklasse/alle/leihe//w_s/s/zuab/0/plus/1/galerie/0/page/2?ajax=yw1`

pay attention to the `ajax` part of it (those dynamic code you need to get is uploaded by ajax)
the last part of the link is `page/2?ajax=yw1` here you can solve your described problem by rotating the number (here it's `2` - the second page, you can change it to any number you need (by using f-strings))

Comment: Thank you for this! I was just wondering how you got the pagination page as i changed the filter when for the table on the link you provided and I could no longer paginate it?

Comment: there is 4 pages with players so you can get them all by something like this `for i in range(1,5): pageTree = requests.get(f'link..galerie/0/page/{i}?ajax=yw1', headers=headers)` then later in this loop you can do with pageTree anything you want to (= you can take from each page any data you want )